# Include specific javascript files in foundation-rails not everything

Tags: zurb-foundation-5

I started using foundation-rails in a project and I would like to know how can I include only the needed javascript files instead of all of them as I'll be using only a couple of things and loading all the javascripts of all files seems a bit unnecessary.

I'm using foundation-rails 5.5.2 and I have this in my application.js

```
//= require foundation
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line just requires the [foundation.js file in gem vendors/assets/javascripts](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/foundation.js) which in turn just requires the individual files. If you take a look at that file you can just copy paste the individual `requires` to pick what you need and replace the `//= require foundation` that it automatically put in your manifest.